Intersection of subalgebras in an abelian monoidal category
$\require{AMScd}$Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an abelian monoidal category, and let $(M,m,e)$ be an algebra in $\mathcal{C}$, where

$M$ is an object in $\mathcal{C}$,
$m: M \otimes M \to M$ is the multiplication morphism,
$e: 1\to M$ is the unit morphism,

satisfying the associativity and unit axioms.
A subalgebra $X$ of $M$ is defined as an algebra $(X, m_X, e_X)$ together with an monomorphism $i_X: X \to M$ which is an algebra morphism,  i.e.

$e = i_X \circ e_X$,
$i_X \circ m_X = m \circ (i_X \otimes i_X)$.

Let $A$ and $B$ be two subalgebras of $M$. According to [Fr64, §1.5], the intersection $A \cap B$ can be described by the following pullback diagram:
$$
\begin{CD}
A \cap B @>j_A>> A \\
@VVj_BV @VVi_AV \\
B @>i_B>> M
\end{CD}
$$
Question: Is there an algebra structure on $A \cap B$ such that $i_A \circ j_A = i_B \circ j_B$ is an algebra monomorphism?
Roughly speaking, we are asking whether the intersection of two subalgebras is still a subalgebra. This is obviously true for $\mathcal{C} = \text{Vec}$, but it may not hold in general (although I do not have a counterexample at the moment). If so, what happens when we restrict to a tensor category $\mathcal{C}$ over $\mathbb{C}$? If it also does not hold in this case, what would be a minimal relevant assumption on $\mathcal{C}$?

Reference:
[Fr64] Freyd, Peter. Abelian Categories: An Introduction to the Theory of Functors. Harper's Series in Modern Mathematics. Harper & Row, Publishers, New York, 1964. xi+164 pp.

Yes, such an algebra structure exists.
In fact, there is a unique algebra structure on $A \cap B$ such that $j_A : A \cap B \to A$ and $j_B : A \cap B \to B$ are algebra morphisms.
To construct the morphisms $m_{A \cap B} : (A \cap B) \otimes (A \cap B) \to A \cap B$ and $e_{A \cap B} : 1 \to A \cap B$ and check the necessary axioms, one uses the universal property of pullbacks.
For example, to construct $m_{A \cap B}$, we can use
$$m_A \circ (j_A \otimes j_A) : (A \cap B) \otimes (A \cap B) \to A$$
and
$$m_B \circ (j_B \otimes j_B) : (A \cap B) \otimes (A \cap B) \to B.$$
One checks that
$$ i_A \circ m_A \circ (j_A \otimes j_A) = i_B \circ m_B \circ (j_B \otimes j_B)$$
and so there is a unique map $m_{A \cap B} : (A \cap B) \otimes (A \cap B) \to A \cap B$ such that
$$j_A \circ m_{A \cap B} = m_A \circ (j_A \otimes j_A)$$
and
$$j_B \circ m_{A \cap B} = m_B \circ (j_B \otimes j_B).$$
The following diagram summarizes the conclusion.

Note that this includes part of the information needed to show that $j_A$ and $j_B$ are algebra morphisms.
The rest of the argument is similar.
If things are set up correctly, one can actually use the same exact argument to show that the functor $\mathrm{Alg}(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{C}$ forgetting algebra structures creates limits.
This only requires $\mathcal{C}$ to be a monoidal category.

If we further assume that $A$, $B$, and $M$ are self-dual, can we then deduce that $A \cap B$ is also self-dual?

I think I can prove this, assuming that the tensor product of the aforementioned pullback with itself is still a pullback (meaning that $(A \cap B) \otimes (A \cap B)$ is isomorphic to $(A \otimes A) \cap (B \otimes B)$). However, I am uncertain whether this assumption holds true.

Here is my new post dedicated to this problem: https://mathoverflow.net/q/478858/34538
