Tensor product of intersections in an abelian rigid monoidal category
To what extent can the following results in ${\rm Vec}$ stated in [Ro08, Chapter 14, Exercises 10-12] be extended to abelian rigid monoidal categories?

(10) Let $S_1, S_2$ be subspaces of $U$. Then $$ (S_1 \otimes V) \cap (S_2 \otimes V) \simeq (S_1 \cap S_2) \otimes V $$
(11) Let $S \subseteq U$ and $T \subseteq V$ be subspaces of vector spaces $U$ and $V$, respectively. Then $$ (S \otimes V) \cap (U
\otimes T) \simeq S \otimes T $$
(12) Let $S_1, S_2 \subseteq U$ and $T_1, T_2 \subseteq V$ be subspaces of $U$ and $V$, respectively. Then $$ (S_1 \otimes T_1) \cap (S_2
 \otimes T_2) \simeq (S_1 \cap S_2) \otimes (T_1 \cap T_2) $$

Proof of (10) for any abelian rigid monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$: According to [EGNO, Exercise 1.6.4 and Proposition 2.10.8], the functor $- \otimes V$ is exact in $\mathcal{C}$. The intersection is defined as a pullback of monomorphisms [Fr64, §2.1]. Since a pullback is a finite limit and an exact functor preserves finite limits, the result follows. $\square$
Question: To what extent can (11) and (12) be extended to any abelian rigid monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$?
Given that the statements hold for $\mathcal{C} = {\rm Vec}$, we can already infer that they more generally apply to the semisimple case.

References:
[EGNO15] Etingof, Pavel; Gelaki, Shlomo; Nikshych, Dmitri; Ostrik, Victor. Tensor categories. Mathematical Surveys and Monographs, 205. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2015. xvi+343 pp.
[Fr64] Freyd, Peter. Abelian categories. An introduction to the theory of functors. Harper's Series in Modern Mathematics. Harper & Row, Publishers, New York, 1964. {\rm xi}+164 pp.
[Ro08] Roman, Steven. Advanced linear algebra. Third edition. Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 135. Springer, New York, 2008. xviii+522 pp.

Here's a useful lemma to check whether a square in an abelian category is a pullback square:
Lemma: A square $A_0\to (A_1,A_2)\to A_3$ with $A_0\to A_1, A_2\to A_3$ being monomorphisms is a pullback square if and only if the induced morphism $A_1/A_0\to A_3/A_2$ is a monomorphism.
Proof : The map $A_1\times_{A_3} A_2\to A_1$ is a monomorphism (as pulled back from a monomorphism), and the inclusion $A_0\to A_1$ factors through it. Therefore, the map $A_1/A_0\to A_3/A_2$ factors through $A_1/A_0\to A_1/(A_1\times_{A_3}A_2) $ - for the total composite to be a monomorphism, this must be one as well, thus proving the claim.
In the situation of (11), $X\otimes -$ preserves monomorphisms for all $X$, and hence the square $S\otimes T\to (S\otimes V, U\otimes T)\to U\otimes V$ satisfies our assumptions.
The situation of (12), note that $(S_i\otimes T_i)= (S_i\otimes V)\cap (U\otimes T_i)$ so that we may reduce to question (11): $(S_1\otimes T_1)\cap (S_2\otimes T_2)= (S_1\otimes V)\cap (U\otimes T_1) \cap (S_2\otimes V)\cap (U\otimes T_2)$. Using that $-\otimes V$ and $U\otimes -$ preserve pullbacks and that intersections commute, we get $((S_1\cap S_2) \otimes V)\cap (U\otimes (T_1\cap T_2))$ and then we apply (11) again to get $((S_1\cap S_2)\otimes (T_1\cap T_2))$.
